# What mode of memory at the time linux kernel was loaded?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel

Can anyone tell me what the memory mode is at the time linux kernel is loaded (by bootloader)? As [this link](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkernel.html) says, the memory mode is real mode then the linux kernel will ask user to choose video mode and then switch to protected mode, but I do not seen it ask me to choose any thing, so is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of the x86 architecture and the Linux boot process,  when the computer is turned on, it is in real mode; the kernel then enters protected mode after setting the needed descriptor tables. This is done by the code in the files [`pm.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6.4/arch/x86/boot/pm.c) and [`pmjump.S`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6.4/arch/x86/boot/pmjump.S).

The diagram on [this page](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/kernel-boot-process) explains better than I could.

As for the "choose video mode", there was a `vga=` parameter, which isn't much used anymore and [is deprecated](http://wiki.debian.org/GrubTransition); those instructions you link to are quite old.

Comment: BTW, so the grub bootloader switch to 32bit protected mode, and then do somethings, load kernel and back to real mode before give control to kernel?

Comment: No. The bootloader passes control to the kernel which then enters the protected mode, where it stays (since the protected mode gives the kernel the features it needs).